# printbibliography messing up appendix header with fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, appendices

I have a problem where `\printbibliography` sets the `fancyhdr` head as centred "Bibliography" and it doesn't change when we get to the Appendix. I tried to work around it by using `\fancyhead[CE,CO]{Appendix}` just before the Appendix. However, now the last page of my Bibliography has the header "Appendix" and the first Appendix page - the header "Bibliography". My code is as follows:

main:

```
\backmatter 

    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \pagenumbering{roman}

    \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}
    \printbibliography
    
    % without the following line, the header of all appendix pages is "Bibliography"
    \fancyhead[CE,CO]{Appendix}
    \input{./misc/appendix}
```

appendix:

```
\appendix
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}

\renewcommand{\thelstlisting}{\Alph{section}.\arabic{lstlisting}}
\chapter*{Appendices}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendices}


\section{Program Source Code}
...
```

Visualization:

[image]

(Updated question):
Minimal code to reproduce:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,appendixprefix]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[CE,CO]{\leftmark}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
}

\usepackage{appendix}

\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    
    \mainmatter
        \chapter{Structure of the Paper}
    
    \backmatter 
        \appendix
        \chapter*{Appendices}
    
        \fancyhead[CE,CO]{Appendix}
         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendices}
        
        \section{Functional Tests Source Code}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [KOMA-script bundle](//ctan.org/pkg/koma-bundle) has it's own module to deal with headers/footers called [`scrlayer`](//ctan.org/pkg/scrlayer). Using [`fancyhdr`](//ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) explicitly as an alternative causes a warning within the `.log`:

```
Class scrbook Warning: Usage of package `fancyhdr' together
(scrbook)              with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended.
(scrbook)              I'd suggest to use 
(scrbook)              package `scrlayer' or `scrlayer-scrpage', because
(scrbook)              they support KOMA-Script classes.
(scrbook)              With `fancyhdr' several features of class `scrbook'
(scrbook)              like options `headsepline', `footsepline' or command
(scrbook)              `\MakeMarkcase' and the commands `\setkomafont' and
(scrbook)              `\addtokomafont' for the page style elements need
(scrbook)              explicite user intervention to work.
(scrbook)              Nevertheless, using requested
(scrbook)              package `fancyhdr' on input line 5.
```

Regardless, if you still want to use `fancyhdr`, you need to reissue the appropriate page style as the first page of a chapter is handled differently. Since the `plain` page style has been (re)defined to use `\leftmark` and `\leftmark` doesn't change with a `\chapter*`, you either need to change that manually, or change the page style (to something like `fancy`) for that page:

```
\appendix
\chapter*{Appendices}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendices}

\fancyhead{}%
\fancyhead[CE,CO]{Appendix}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this helped only partially! The first page of the Appendix still has the Bibliography header :( I tried adding \clearpage and \cleardoublepage everywhere between the bibliography and the appendix, I even changed the fancy header before the bibliography to something else, but on the appendix header it still says Bibliography! It makes no sense!

Comment: @coffee-and-code: Please provide code that I (we) can copy-and-paste-and-compile as see exactly what you're seeing. See [this post](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764) on how to create a minimal working example (MWE) with a bibliography.

Comment: I updated my question with the code to reproduce. I created a new overleaf document with just that code and it turns out that the bibliography has nothing to do with it, it just shows the title of the previous chapter/section as header on the appendix.

Comment: I tried to exclude as much as possible from the code and updated the minimal example and it still shows the previous chapter as the header of the appendix... I literally do not see what can cause this behaviour

Answer (score 0):

If someone else is having the same problem and wondering - the problem was the `chapter*` command. I managed to fix it like this:

```
\appendix
\renewcommand\thechapter{}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\chapter{Appendix}
```